# MPI fortran MPI_Irecv - specify several tags?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am using MPI_recv in F thus:

```
call MPI_Irecv(winner,4,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG, &
         &             MPI_COMM_WORLD,ireq,ierr)
```

But rather than MPI_ANY_TAG I want to specify a few different tags. Is there any way to do this without looping over the call?

Comment: It is not possible to specify more than one tag in the receive filter. It is either a fixed tag or all possible tags (i.e. `MPI_ANY_TAG`).

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could find the right message is to do something like a bunch of calls to `MPI_IMPROBE`. Each time, you specify a different tag from the group you want. Eventually one of them will match and you can receive that message with the corresponding `MPI_MRECV`.